# User access/authorization to web app secured with azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

My company has an Azure Active Directory, and my web application hosted in App Service is currently using the built-in option AAD authentication mechanism (AppService -> Setting -> Authentication/Authorization -> Choose AAD as provider) to allow people from our AAD to login. This is very convenient as we do not need to change our application at all.
However, I would like to know whether there is an option to decide who in our AAD can actually login to the application? We would like to limit certain users only to access our application.

Is this something configurable from Azure or need to be handled at application level?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can configure the app in AAD to only allow certain users.

Find the app from Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications.
Go to its Properties and set *User assignment required?* to *Yes*.
Now you can assign users from the Users & Groups tab.

Comment: Thanks. I have attempted to turn on the option and assigned a user. However after the user is logged in, he is greeted with the
"XXX needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it." message.

I checked the required permission settings of my application, none of them require admin consent. I am quite baffled with this message.

Comment: @DavidBL I have the same issue, did you ever solve this?